# How to export a .FBX file　without any extra things ( and Import it in Unity)?

Tags: export, unity, .fbx

[image]

Like the picture above, it is the model of Offcial_IA_MMD_Model. I used the mmd-tools adons to import it. The model contains physics simulations;mostly related to the skirt and the hair.

[image]

The setting I did to export the model as .FBX is the picture above.

[image: Unity_Import]

I dragged the exported file in Unity but, it seems there is something wrong with the model. I think it may be displaying object related to the physical simulation. How to import the model like the first picture which contain the physical simulation without anything unneeded?

Answer (score 1):

Select the meshes you want to export and make sure to tick "Selected Objects" in the export window